# RecyclerView crashing while launching

Tags: xml, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I was trying to implement a RecyclerView, it shows no errors while debugging but it crushes when ckick on the textView to intent to dayone.xml activity (RecyclerView layout).

I get this in logcat:

```
   Process: com.example.mozillaevent, PID: 15060
    java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.cardview.widget.CardView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
        at com.example.mozillaevent.Adapter$ViewHolder.<init>(Adapter.kt:37)
        at com.example.mozillaevent.Adapter.onCreateViewHolder(Adapter.kt:16)
        at com.example.mozillaevent.Adapter.onCreateViewHolder(Adapter.kt:11)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7078)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6235)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22496)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6528)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:334)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22496)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6528)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:536)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22496)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6528)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:334)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22496)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6528)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1857)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1701)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1610)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22496)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6528)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:334)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:1146)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22496)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6528)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3743)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3207)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2166)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8887)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1280)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:1019)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:911)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1248)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:900)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8668)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1109)
```

these are the following classes:

- class Adapter
- data class Items
- MainActvity  + ScreenOne class

```
class Adapter(val items: List<Items>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val item = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.day1, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(item)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val items = items[position]
        holder.bind(items)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return (items.size)
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

        var image: ImageView
        var cardName: TextView
        var day: TextView
        var description: TextView

        init {
            image = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageBox)
            description = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.descriptionBox)
            day = view.findViewById(R.id.tvDay)
            cardName = view.findViewById(R.id.tvName)
        }

        fun bind(element: Items) {
            image.setImageResource(element.image)
            description.text = element.description
            cardName.text = element.cardName
            day.text = element.day

        }


    }
}
```

//data class

```
data class Items (
    val image: Int,
    val cardName: String,
    val day: String,
    val description: String
        )
```

```
class ScreenOne : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.dayone)


        val recyclerview =findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)

        val elements = listOf(
            Items(R.drawable.img, "Android workshop", "tuesday", "Make your first app"
            ),
            Items(R.drawable.img, "Android workshop", "tuesday", "Make your first app"
            ),
            Items(R.drawable.img, "Android workshop", "tuesday", "Make your first app"
            ),
            Items(R.drawable.img, "Android workshop", "tuesday", "Make your first app"
            ),
            Items(R.drawable.img, "Android workshop", "tuesday", "Make your first app"
            ),

        )

        recyclerview.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@ScreenOne)
        }
        recyclerview.adapter= Adapter(elements)


    }
}
```

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val intent = Intent(this, ScreenOne::class.java)

        val btn = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvDayOne)
     btn.setOnClickListener {
         startActivity(intent)
     }


    }
}
```

//activity.main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/day1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardOne"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/lightGray"
            android:elevation="30dp"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
            app:cardElevation="15dp">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvDayOne"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="DAY 1"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="100sp"

                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></TextView>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/lightGray"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
            app:cardElevation="15dp">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="DAY 2"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="100sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></TextView>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/Orange"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
            app:cardElevation="15dp"

>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="DAY 3"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="100sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></TextView>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/lightGray"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
            app:cardElevation="15dp">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="DAY 4"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="100sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></TextView>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

//day1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
       android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="400dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="9dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="239dp">


            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/descriptionBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvDes"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/dateLayout"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        tools:text="Mozilla description "
                        tools:textColor="@color/black"
                        tools:textSize="15dp">

                    </TextView>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/dateLayout"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/tvName"
                        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvName"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvDay"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            tools:text="Thursday">

                        </TextView>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/descriptionBox"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        tools:ignore="NotSibling"
                        android:text="Workshop Name"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="25dp">

                    </TextView>


                </RelativeLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/descriptionBox"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/img">

            </ImageView>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

//dayone.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: Can you share the crush report, check the logcat.

Comment: check the post, i've added the crush report from logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the stack trace, the crash is due to trying to cast a `CardView` to a `TextView`.

You can also see there that it happens during initialization of `Adapter$ViewHolder` class.

The culprit is likely `description = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.descriptionBox)` since `R.id.descriptionBox` is defined as a `CardView` in the layout but you're trying to cast it to a `TextView`. (maybe you meant to use `R.id.tvDes` instead?)

Comment: Sincerely, I did not pay attention to that! thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can not set the text to a cardView, i guess you wanted to use `tvDes` like below:

```
        init {
            image = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageBox)
            //Below line changed
            description = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvDes)
            day = view.findViewById(R.id.tvDay)
            cardName = view.findViewById(R.id.tvName)
        }
```